# How do I Unpivot and Pivot with merged cells with PowerQuery

Tags: excel, office365, powerquery

I have been tasked with taking data from an export and converting it to a report. My initial thought was to do it with VBA, but I think I can do it with Power Query, the problem is I know very little about it. But here is what I am looking to do.

[image]
In the example above you can see the way the data comes to me
Row 1 has currently 11 different categories that has 4 cells merged into 1.
When I input it with Power Query the headers look like this

|  |  |  |  | AS | null | null | null | BT | null | null | null |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Region | Mgmt Area | Area | Date | Used - AS | Avail - AS | % Booked - AS | Status - AS | Used - BT | Avail - BT | % Booked - BT | Status - BT |

What I would like my final result to be

|  |  | 3/1/2024 - Fri |  |  |  | 3/2/2024 - Sat |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | Category | Total | Used | Avail | Available % | Total | Used | Avail | Available % |
| P1 - Nodes 100-500 | AS | 97 | 0 | 97 | 100% | 1 | 0 | 1 | 100% |
| P1 - Nodes 100-500 | BT | 2 | 0 | 2 | 100% | 96 | 20 | 76 | 79% |

1. The Categories in the first row will be put into a column
2. Total will be the sum of Available and Used
3. Available % is the avail/total
4. The dates become the new grouping at the top
5. The % booked and Status columns can be removed

I believe in order to accomplish what I am looking to do I will need to Unpivot and then re pivot the data. The issue I am running into is with the merged cells in the top row and how to get a unique list, remove the nulls, and move to a column

While playing with the Pivot and unpivot options I have tried to remove the first row
Promote the new first row to headers, and Unpivot the data.

A kick in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I am not sure if I am on the right track or not.

Comment: To narrow down your question about merged cells, the typical way to handle this is to use Transpose so that the "AS-null-null-null-BT-null-null-null" row becomes a column, then use Fill Down so it becomes "AS-AS-AS-AS-BT-BT-BT-BT". Then you can Transpose again to get back to the original layout, or group, pivot, etc. as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will play with that to see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gives you any ideas

```
let   Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted Headers", {"Region", "Mgmt Area", "Area", "Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" - ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Type", "Category"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Region", "Mgmt Area"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Area", "Date", "Category"}, {
        {"total", each List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Type] = "Avail" or [Type] = "Used")[Value])},
    {"avail", each List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Type] = "Avail")[Value])},
    {"used", each List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Type] = "Used")[Value])}

   }),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Available", each [avail]/[total],type number),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Area", "Date", "Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns1", "Custom", each Text.From([Date]) & "-" &[Attribute]),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Date", "Attribute"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[Custom]), "Custom", "Value", List.Sum)
in    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @horseyride. I implemented this and have been going through step by step to understand how it was done.